# Android Studio Dolphin not showing app logging for EMULATOR

Tags: android-studio

I have lots of `Log.d()` messages for debugging purposes.  These show up just fine in the Logcat panel of Android Studio when running the app on a connected *physical device*.  But when running the same app on an *emulator*, these log messages don't show in the Logcat.

This is for Android Studio Dolphin, and they've recently changed the Logcat panel, to show colours etc, but I'm not sure if it broke then or was broken before.  Or whether I'm just missing an option somewhere.

Note that the Logcat panel now has a "package:mine" filter to show only log messages from your own app.  This works for the physical device, but for the emulator it just filters out everything... nothing left.  When the filter is disabled, there *are* system log messages appearing, so it seems to be just my own `Log.d()` messages that aren't making it.

[image]

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

Comment: Happen on Emulator, restarting Emulator doesn't work. The solution is to restart Android Studio..

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this same issue—happens with and without Patch 1.  The workaround I uncovered was to, simply, disconnect the physical device.  Once I did this, I could see all the logcat information from the emulated device.  Pretty sad how this stuff escapes Quality Assurance testing.

Comment: Ok thanks for sharing... I'll try that next time.  Can't remember whether the physical device was connected too, but quite likely it was.

Comment: Yes.  Same issue here.  Your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

OK so the next time I fired up Android Studio (with my PC having been restarted in the meantime) and then fired up the emulator again... now the logcat *is* showing output from the running app as I would expect.  So it must have just been a temporary glitch, with the usual "turn it off and on again" solution working.  I also notice (which I hadn't done before) that the "Run" tab also shows logcat output from the app (though not prettified with any colour) and I'm not sure if that would have shown logcat output even if there was nothing in the Logcat tab itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, It seems to be a bug, there are two options, I prefer the first way cause it doesn't restart the whole IDE.

**First solution**:
Open the `terminal` from the bottom panel (tabs on the left corner).
Run these two commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

**Second solution**:
Select the File *menu* > *Invalidate Caches* > *Invalidate and Restart*